# Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory'. with the Nuget package version 1.0.94.1

Tags: .net, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I am getting this error with the Nuget package for SQLite 1.0.94.1. I fiddled around with the various app.config sections, helped by similar questions about previous versions of this package, but I cannot get it to work. Below is the app.config as I found it after installing the Nuget package. I deleted the app.config prior to installing it. I only added the connectionstrings after that.

So, where is the problem??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <!--Added by me, the rest of the app.config was constructed by installing the SQLite package -->
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PrivateMessengerContext"  connectionString="DataSource=|DataDirectory|\PrivateMessengerDb.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
    <add name="PasswordContext" connectionString="DataSource=|DataDirectory|\PasswordDb.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
    <!--
        NOTE: The extra "remove" element below is to prevent the design-time
          support components within EF6 from selecting the legacy ADO.NET
          provider for SQLite (i.e. the one without any EF6 support).  It
          appears to only consider the first ADO.NET provider in the list
          within the resulting "app.config" or "web.config" file.
    -->
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That app.config does noy look right. Pls delete and only install the sqlite.ef6 package - but expdct it to be shaky, suggest yiu report any issues at system.data.sqlite.org

Comment: @ErikEJ I uninstalled the package and reinstalled only the EF6 package. Less dependencies were installed now, but the resuling app.config is identical and the error remains. The package has more than 4.000 downloads, so there must be wizards out there that got it working.

Comment: When do you get the error?

Comment: @ErikEJ I am using code first. So the error pops up the first time the DbContext (PrivateMessengerContext) is used.

Comment: Getting the same issue.

Comment: @pksorensen I am going to abandon SQLite in favour of SQLServerCompact as no help is forthcoming, neither here or on the support forum.

Comment: also dropped the idea of sqlight

Comment: @pksorensen and dabbernl Glad to hear it, I actively support the Sql Ce EF6 providers, so let me know via Codeplex or here if you encounter any issues!

Comment: I'm honestly stunned that this stuff STILL doesn't work as advertised 5 years after the fact. Eg, install the correct x86 SQLite bundle, create a new VS forms project, nuget the full SQLlite package in, add a new 'Entity Data Model/EF designer from database', take all the defaults, test the connection. All good. But try to actually use the framework and it breaks with 'Unable to determine the provider name ...' unless you faff around with the app.config!! This is complete rubbish. Seriously, if you don't already have a reason to use SQLite, look elsewhere and save yourself the frustration.

Answer (score 23):

Add one more provider

`<provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />`

move

`<add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />`

bellow

`<remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />`

and change the provider name to `providerName="System.Data.SQLite` in your connection string.

**EDIT**:
See also http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview/2be4298631c01be99475

Comment: I have the same problem the difference is that I use entityframework.6.1.3.nupkg, so when I implement your advice throw this  exception The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded.

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me was to follow the comment on 2015-04-29 08:33:33 in the [SQLite ticket](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview/2be4298631c01be99475):

> If you switch project target platform from 4.5.1 to 4 and reinstall nuget package you will have it all working(even if you later return it back to 4.5.1)"

Might have a similar effect on config to Mihail's answer, not sure.

Comment: Miraculously solved mine.. Just to note (as it is said on the answer); my platform version was 4.5  only. With going back to platform version 4, reinstalling SQLite and then returning back to 4.5 got it working.

Comment: After that I had another problem, because Sqllite.CodeFirst required a recent EntityFramework. I had to manually update EntityFramework from 6.1.0 to 6.1.3 (cliking on version number). Now I'm done, on .NET v4.0.