# SQLite connection not appearing in Entity Data Model Wizard (vs2015)

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6

What I did is,

1) Created a project in vs2015 (.Net Framework 4.6)
2) Installed System.Data.SQLite from Nuget. Actually System.Data.SQLite(1.0.105.1),System.Data.SQLite.Core(1.0.105.1),System.Data.SQLite.EF6(1.0.105.1),System.Data.SQLite.Linq(1.0.105.1),EntityFramework(6.0.0) were installed
3) Updated EntityFramework to 6.1.3 in Nuget
4) Tried to create Entity Data Model from a local Sqlite database
5) Rebuilded the whole solution

But when I tried to create a new database connection, SQLite connection was not appearing in the data source.

Can anyone figure out this issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configsections>

<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->

<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />

<entityframework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
<provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />


<system.data>
<dbproviderfactories> 
<remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
<add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
<remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
<add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK the designer support is not included in the nuget packages of SQLite: you will need to install the package that is indicated for the version of Visual Studio that you are using.

According to the [System.Data.SQLite downloads page](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) currently the only package providing designer support in VS 2015 are the *Setups for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.6) sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.105.1.exe (16.93 MiB)*, which contains the following sentence in its description:

> **This is the only setup package that is capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio 2015.**

Comment: So does downloading *sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.105.1.exe* mean you don't have to download the NuGet packages, or do you still need both? If it's the latter, why are both needed?

Comment: @JacobStamm: the answer is also in the aforementioned [downloads page](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki):
 _The setup packages are intended to be installed only on developer machines and then only when the design-time components for Visual Studio are required. In theory, they can be installed on customer machines as well; however, this type of deployment is not recommended._ Moreover: the only packages containing the design-time components are 32 bits, and I am sure that you still want to use the 64 bits libraries in some cases...